# MariaDB GET DIAGNOSTICS

Tags: mysql, database, linux, diagnostics, mariadb

I recently searched for a possibility to get the error a database action has caused. In MySQL 5.6 and MariaDB 10 this is possible through the

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS
```

command. The corresponding example is

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT
```

But MariaDB throws an error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GET 
DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1              
@p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT' at line 1
```

I already checked the version, I have 10.0.3-MariaDB

Thanks in advance for your help

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB supports GET DIAGNOSTICS since MariaDB 10.0.4. You should upgrade your MariaDB version. The syntax is correct, therefore it will be accepted.